# Passport successRedirect not working!!1

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, ejs, passport-local

I've tried everything. I went through all of the answers ever answered to questions with the slightest similarity. I'm desperate.

I'm using passport module for my website and successRedirect is not working, while failureRedirect does exactly what it's supposed to do.
this is **users.js**, it does the routing.

```
    'use strict';

     const passport = require('passport');
     const User = require('../models/user');

     module.exports = function(_, passport){
      return {
    SetRouting: function(router){
      console.log('got it');  
      router.get('/', this.indexPage);
      router.get('/signup', this.getSignUp);
      router.get('/home', this.homePage);
      router.post('/signup', this.postSignUp);
    },

    indexPage: function(req, res){
        console.log('got index page');
        return res.render('index');
    },

    getSignUp: function(req, res){
        console.log('got signup page');
        return res.render('signup');

    },

    homePage: function(req, res){
        console.log('got home page');
        return res.render('home');
    },

    postSignUp: passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/signup',
        failureFlash: true
    }),
}
```

and this is **passport-local.js**, where I do my local strategy function call:

```
  'use strict';

  const passport = require('passport');
  const User = require('../models/user');
  const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
     done(null, user.id);
  });

 passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
     User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user);
     });
 });

passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
 }, (req, email, password, done) => {

User.findOne({'email': email}, (err, user) => {
   if(err){
       return done(err);
   }

    if(user){
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'User with email already exist'));
    }

    const newUser = new User();
    newUser.username = req.body.username;
    newUser.fullname = req.body.username;
    newUser.email = req.body.email;
    newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(req.body.password);

    newUser.save((err) => {
        done(null, newUser);
    });
});
}));
```

i'd appriciate your help so so so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is named `'local.signup'`. Strategy names can't contain a period.

There are a number of places where Passport uses the strategy name as an object key and variable identifier. For example, [Passport's Authenticator](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/authenticator.js) constructs, and later references, an Object of strategies with the strategy names as keys:

```
Authenticator.prototype.use = function(name, strategy) {
  ...  
  this._strategies[name] = strategy;
  return this;
};
```

For this to work, `name` must be a valid Javascript identifier, meaning no periods.